# upgrade was jdk failed to due Version 8 requires

Tags: websphere

When we upgrading was from 9.0.0.7 to 9.0.5.11 using command

`./imcl install com.ibm.websphere.ND.v90_9.0.5011.20220222_1524  -repositories /soft/was90511 -installationDirectory /was/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -acceptLicense -sP`

it said

> CRIMA1270E ERROR: The IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment package requires the IBM SDK, Java Technology Edition, Version 8 package. Install IBM SDK, Java Technology Edition, Version 8 together with IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment .

Then we choosed to upgrade the jdk first by

`./imcl install com.ibm.java.jdk.v8_8.0.7005.20220209_1019  -repositories /soft/jdk80705 -installationDirectory /was/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -acceptLicense -sP`

from 8.0.5.11 to 8.0.7.5, but still met the below error :

> ERROR: The installation package 'IBM SDK, Java Technology Edition, Version 8' requires components supplied by other packages.
> The required components might be supplied by the following installation packages:
> Package: Any IBM product edition that supports IBM SDK Java Technology Edition for Installation Manager consult the product documentation".

Is there any thing wrong with my command?

Comment: You have support? Call IBM

Comment: That shouldn't happen on an upgrade, did you uninstall 9.0.0.7 first? There's no need to, if you did.

Comment: we didn't uninstall it and just do upgrade. maybe we need to contact ibm supports

Answer (score 0):

You should install the WAS and SDK offering at the same time, as depicted at the bottom of this document:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=offerings-installing-product-by-using-command-line#d55e1182

> imcl install com.ibm.websphere.ND.v90 com.ibm.java.jdk.8

(yes, it is really space-separated)

Answer (score 0):

./imcl install com.ibm.websphere.ND.v90_9.0.5011.20220222_1524  -repositories /soft/was90511 -installationDirectory /was/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -acceptLicense -sP

Here we are updating the binaries so i think we need to give the update instead of install  just try it once. below for your reference.

./imcl **update** com.ibm.websphere.ND.v90_9.0.5011.20220222_1524  -repositories /soft/was90511 -installationDirectory /was/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -acceptLicense -sP